# Write a Method like Vector.at()

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I would like to know how is that the .at() method works, like the one in the Vector class of the C++, a method that both ways returns and/or assign a value to the member of the array.
i don't know if with a macro i can do it, or declaring 2 method with same name... any help?

i have been trying to find and open the file of vector, to see how it was written, that specific method, but i have not found it.

(its for a different structure i am building, but i would like to access to them with only one method)

Example of what i mean.

```
vec.at(x) = value;
newValue = vec.at(x);
```

Comment: Did you look at their function signature? It pretty much gives it away.

Comment: i haven't found the vector header, and if so, i also would like to know how the methods where written, to see if they are as efficient as i think, or to re-write it.

Answer (score 5):

You have to return a reference to the value. So instead of

```
int at(int idx)
```

You just do

```
int& at(int idx)
```

References are very similar to pointers with the difference that you cannot and dont have to dereference them in order to manipulate the value they are referencing

Answer (score -2):

There should be an easy way to open any source file within the IDE.  I use this feature all of the time to review the Standard Library, especially when wanting to review the signature of the member functions of `std::vector`, `std::map`, `std::list`, etc., without having to open a browser window.

Hopefully the IDE used has something similar to "open file at cursor".  Since the IDE is not known by the question content, a more generic procedure is presented.

1) Make sure the relevant header name is in a `#include` line.  For example:

```
#include <vector>
```

2) Move the editor cursor so that the cursor is clearly shown under a section of the header file name (e.g. `vector`).

3) Within the IDE run the "open file at cursor" command.

4) The IDE should now show the file highlighted by the cursor in its own window / tab, and there is no need to manually navigate to the area where all header files are located on the development system.

5) Search the newly opened file as desired.

Comment: It is good advice.  But you probably have to keep in mind that most C++ users at SO don't have a fancy IDE like that.  It is a language that needs to be programmed the hard way, perhaps, avoid hinting that it can be "visual" :)